# How to get mapid for a map created in an editor using mapbox.js?

Tags: mapbox

I have created a map using mapbox.js for various layer. I have the html file for it. I want to get the mapid for this map so that I can embed it in my website. How should I get the mapid?

Answer (score 2):

A little more info: first you want to make a map with Mapbox:

https://www.mapbox.com/foundations/make-your-first-map/

Then you want to share the map's map ID:

https://www.mapbox.com/foundations/share-your-map/

Comment: I mean, I have a html file offline. I have used various projects from mapbox to create a customized map for myself offline. Now I want to host this map on mapbox so that I can get a mapid for this customized map and I can share this.

Comment: What format is the map in? If it's a folder of map tiles now, you can use something like [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) to convert it to MBTiles for upload.

Comment: is it possible to use the new Mapbox GL styles in conjunction with raster tiles? like passing a parameter into the url ? https://api.mapbox.com/v4/johndpope.053e7m8m/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mapbox.com/studio/tilesets/

Click on the drop down for the tilesets as shown in screenshot.
This will get you the id for that chosen tileset view.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

you need to sign in in to this site https://www.mapbox.com/ and you can get the MAP ID

Comment: I mean, I have a html file offline. I have used various projects from mapbox to create a customized map for myself offline. Now I want to host this map on mapbox so that I can get a mapid for this customized map and I can share this. @incanus

Comment: @ashok_p as the question is OP have account but dont know where to hit , Kindly give the exact **URL**